# Cancel audio when navigating with StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I am using `react-navigation-stack` in my React Native App. However, am having issues with the audio continuing to play after a user leaves the current screen. How can I disable audio when the user navigates to a different screen in my app?

I have a StackNavigator set up as follows:

```
//App.js
...
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {screen: Main},
    Song: {screen: Song},
    SongList: {screen: SongList},
    About: {screen: About}
})
...
```

On the `Song` screen there are lyrics as well as an audio button. When the user clicks the audio button the audio plays for them using the following code:

```
//Song.js
...
playAudio = (filepath) => {
    var s = new Sound('audio/' + filepath, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
        if (error){
             console.log('error', error)
        }
        else {
            s.play(()=>{
                s.release()
            })
        }
    })
}
...
```

As you can see audio is released when the audio file finishes. However, how can I also set it so that it stops playing (is released) when the user navigates away from the current page?

Answer (score 1):

Use [addListener](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener---subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) with "didBlur" and "didFocus" to detect when user leaves the screen (opens another screen on top of it) and comes back to it. `stop` or `pause` sound on blur, `resume` it on focus. And finally, `release` the sound (and remove listeners) on `componentWillUnmount`

---

added example

```
class SongScreen extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.playAudio('some/filepath')
    this.didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didBlur',
      () => this.sound.pause()
    )
    this.didFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'didFocus',
      () => this.sound.play()
    )
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.didBlurSubscription.remove()
    this.didFocusSubscription.remove()
    this.sound.stop().release()
  }

  playAudio = (filepath) => {
    this.sound = new Sound('audio/' + filepath, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
      } else {
        this.sound.play(() => {
          this.sound.release()
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly would the addListener go? In the Songs screen or the main screen? There's also the suggestion to remove the listener when you are done with it. Where exactly would I use that?

Comment: added example @kojow7

Comment: It does take a few seconds for pause to work, is that normal? It will serve my purposes for now though.

Comment: Hmm, if I press the back arrow twice quickly to go two screens back then it does not seem to invoke the pause.

Comment: I have now changed `didBlur` to `willBlur` and it solves both of those issues for me.